# Finding the angle a projectile hits a rotated circle

Tags: math, trigonometry, angle, euler-angles

I'm trying to find out which side an entity is hit

46-135 - right side

136-225 - back side

226-315 - left side

316-360 and 0-45 - front side

https://i.ibb.co/hKz5n9z/Help.png (Can't post images but this is what i want)

I know the angle the entity is facing and the angle of the projectile when it hits the entity

I've tried things like:

Math.abs(entityRotation - attackRotation) % 360;

Math.abs(180 - entityRotation - attackRotation) % 360;
etc.

But I cant seem to find an equation that works for all angles.

If that's not possible I can use two different equations for when one angle is greater than the other.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If projectile always is directed to the circle center, try the next approach
(Python code, uses integer division `//`)
 [result here](https://ideone.com/0p2jKV)

```
print("targdir", " attackdir", "side")
sides = ["front", "right", "back", "left"]
for target in range(0, 361, 45):
    for attack in range(0, 361, 45):
        side = ((attack - target + 585) % 360) // 90
        print(target, attack, sides[side])
```